# I can't even set variables in ExactTarget AmpScript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

this is a beginner AmpScript question.  I can't seem to even get past "Step One" in my attempt to learn AmpScript.

I am trying to follow the "AmpScript 101 tutorial" [located here](http://help.exacttarget.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/ampscript/getting_started_with_ampscript/ampscript_101/)

I am trying to set a list of variables per the first example in the tutorial:

```
    %%[
Var @memid, @fname, @lname, @prefname, @address, @zip, @mempref, @plat
Set @memid = MemberID
Set @fname = FirstName
Set @lname = LastName
Set @prefname = PrefName
Set @address = Address
Set @zip = Zip
Set @mempref = MemPref
Set @plat = Plat

]%%
```

And the following code works fine with only the variable "@memid" set:

```
%%[
Var @memid, @fname, @lname, @prefname, @address, @zip, @mempref, @plat
Set @memid = MemberID

]%%
```

Then, when I set the variable "@fname," the code also works fine.

```
   %%[
    Var @memid, @fname, @lname, @prefname, @address, @zip, @mempref, @plat
    Set @memid = MemberID
    Set @fname = FirstName

    ]%%
```

Then, again, when I set the variable "@lname" the code also works.

```
 %%[
    Var @memid, @fname, @lname, @prefname, @address, @zip, @mempref, @plat
    Set @memid = MemberID
    Set @fname = FirstName
    Set @lname = LastName

    ]%%
```

But if I try to set any more than those three variables, my code completely breaks.  Why is this happening?  I've searched and searched for an answer, and I can't seem to figure out what's going on.

For example, this code will throw an error:

```
%%[
    Var @memid, @fname, @lname, @prefname, @address, @zip, @mempref, @plat
    Set @memid = MemberID
    Set @fname = FirstName
    Set @lname = LastName
    Set @prefname = PreferredName


    ]%%
```

(The error is "**The SET variable value expresion(*sic*) is invalid. See inner exception for detail.
Script: Set @prefName = PreferredName
Variable Name: @prefname
The SET variable value expresion is invalid. See inner exception for detail.
Script: Set @prefname = PreferredName
Variable Name: @prefname
Index: 4459
ListID: 452**"

Or, when I try to set any other variable such as @address, @zip, @mempref, or @plat, I get a similar error.

Also, any other random variable that I attempt to set creates the same error.  For example, this code:

```
%%[
    Var @grapefruit
    Set @grapefruit = CitrusFruit

    ]%%
```

The code above produces this error: "**The SET variable value expresion(*sic*) is invalid. See inner exception for detail.
Script: Set @grapefruit = CitrusFruit
Variable Name: @grapefruit
Index: 4312
ListID: 452**"

I can't seem to successfully set ANY variables at all apart from three specific ones: @memid, @fname, @lname

The fact that I am only able to set three specific variables makes no sense to me.  But I can't seem to spot what my error is, or where I'm going wrong, and I can't figure out why code in a basic 101 tutorial would not work for me. This is probably a silly, stupid question with an obvious answer,  but I am truly stuck and cannot find a way to get out of the gate with this.

***Information about my development environment:***
I am using the SalesForce Marketing Cloud's development environment.  I'm working under Email > Content > Template-based email.  I have tried writing this same code in a straight HTML email, and I am getting precisely the same errors regardless of whether I'm using straight-up HTML or a template, but am currently working with template-based email. To see if the code is working, I am clicking "Send Preview," selecting a test recipient, and then clicking on "Generate Preview" which then either generates a functioning preview of the e-mail (with variables @memid, @fname, or @lname) or an error message (with any other attempt to set any other variable)

Comment: Have you set up your profile attributes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are running into, is that your account is not yet fully built out.

The reasone why `MemberID`, `FirstName`, `LastName` all work, is that the account already has those set up as profile attributes, and are listed as [personalization strings](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/)

> A profile attribute contains information to characterize a subscriber
>   profile. For example, each subscriber may be asked to provide their
>   gender, birth date, and email address. By default, every account has
>   three profile attributes: Full Name, Email, and User Defined (which is
>   intended as a generic attribute that you can use as needed). You
>   cannot modify these attributes.
>
> A preference attribute characterizes how a subscriber prefers to
>   receive email. These are specified as "yes or no" choices to a
>   declarative statement. For example: "The subscriber prefers to receive
>   email as HTML."
>
> First you must create the profile or preference attribute in your
>   account so there is a place for the system to store the data. You also
>   specify whether an attribute is required information for every
>   subscriber and whether subscribers can see and edit their own
>   attributes in the Profile Center (a link to the Profile Center is
>   included in every email). You can also specifiy profile attributes
>   when you import a subscriber list. See Subscribers for more
>   information.

1. Click the **Subscribers** tab.
2. Click **Profile Management or Preference Management**.
3. Click **Create Attribute**, which opens the Attribute Properties dialog box.
4. Define the **properties** for this attribute.
5. Click **OK** in the Attribute Properties dialog box when done.

Note: If you marked the new attribute as a required field, all subscriber imports now must include this field. You may want to include a default value so that records can be saved even if a value isn't provided.

You will then be able to access those properties in your AMPscript.

Comment: Great, make sure to check this as answered!